# What is the best option to separate REST query search terms from options?

Tags: rest

Let's say I have a REST API `/cars`. If I do `GET /cars` I will get all cars (if I am allowed). But if I want to get only those cars that are red, I might do `GET /cars?color=red`.

Now let's assume that I want to sort them, say my options are ascending vs descending.

`GET /cars?color=red&sort=asc`

The problem here is that `sort` is not a search term, it is an option. This makes it difficult for the server to differentiate between search *terms* `color=red` and search *options* `sort=asc`.

It is also a bad way to design an API, since one day you might actually *want* to use `sort` as a field you can search on (as opposed to an option).

How would people recommend constructing this search API? Here are the options I have found:

1. Leave it as is, knowing that some fields are, by definition, options and not terms.
2. Special flags for search terms, e.g. `search.color=red&search.year=2010&sort=asc`
3. Special flags for search options, e.g. `color=red&year=2010&option.sort=asc`
4. Special flag for the whole thing, e.g. `search=[color=red&year=2010]&sort=asc` (with the `[..]` section URL encoded)

Thoughts?

Comment: You can use `path parameter` as an approach. For example 
`/cars?color=red/asc`

Comment: Hmm, that is an interesting approach. So you eliminate search options entirely, just make them subsidiary to the key/value of the search terms?

Comment: Of course you will decide which approach is preferred for your task. This is just one of them. See more about it here: https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html

Comment: Since I am designing it, I have options. But I have always extracted anything repetitive into separate libs/toolkits. That forces me to think more generically (and staying DRY). I'd like to think if there is a "right" way to do this, although probably, as you said, it is about flavour and taste.

Answer (score 2):

How about use of OData
http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/

OData v2

```
GET /cars?$orderby=Rating asc
GET /cars?$filter=color eq red
GET /cars$filter=color eq red and year eq 2000&$skip=2&$top=2&$orderby=category/rating desc
```

Or check OData library and URI syntax of version 3 or 4.
OData is some kind of standard and supported in .NET and in Java and JavaScript. There are well established libraries.

Comment: Thanks, checking it now.

Comment: I'm not overly enamoured of the rest of the odata structure - e.g. I prefer `/Categories/1` over `/Categories(1)` and some of the other stuff - but the idea of search *options* starting with `$` while anything plain is passed as a search *term* is nice, and aligns well with AngularJS to boot.

Comment: It depedends which technology is used. As example .NET ASP.NET WebAPI 2 supports REST pathes additionally with OData filtering syntax. I think in Java maybe combination is also possible and with such combination you can have pathes like /Categories/1, or /Categories/1/SubCategories?$filter etc

Comment: And it up to you and your project with selected technology stack to decide which will be more reasonable and easier use OData or use some defined set of URL/query string parameters

Comment: Right now, I am leaning towards standard query string with `$` style options.

Comment: Then personally I would either emulate OData "mix-syntax" or use very simple query string or URL params even without $. So to your answer - leav it as it is, assuming that you specifying search/filter options and terms - GET /cars?color=red&year=2010&sortDirection=asc&sortBy=model

Comment: what about the pollution? `color` and `red` are search terms (they are both part of records of cars), but `sortBy` is a search option.

Comment: It is easiest, but when think about pollution among query string, there is also URL parts. It depends from technology either it is hard or easy to use URL parts. But many service are using URL, then with URL parts you can pass options using query string and search term using URL part, like google is using only URL but it could look like google.com/mail/u/0/#search/from%3Ame+estimation?sortBy=subjecct&sortOrder=asc

Comment: Or on stack overflow searched: is:question [git] review, where search term - review, with git tag and and only questions with sorting/tab - newest. In this case all is in URL and somehow parsed. But it is more complex but flexible way.

stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20%5bgit%5d%20review